# compare two Object array and match value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I have two Object of array like following

```
var a={
  firstObj: 
    [
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      }
    ]  
};

var b={
  secondObj: [
    {
      _id: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53"
    },
    {
      _id: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c"
    },    
  ]
}
```

I want to check if a.firstObj has matching Ref to b.secondObj._id if it has then I am trying to assign into firstObj element to matching b.secondObj.new but somehow _id is not matching

I am trying through map

```
a.firstObj.map(item =>
               b.secondObj.map((_item, index) => {
               console.log(_item._id.toString());
               console.log(item.Ref.toString());
               if (_item._id == item.Ref) {
                   b.secondObj[index].new = item;
                    }
                })
);
```

Comment: `item.orderRef` to `item.Ref`

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, and is a string representation of a JavaScript Object. I don't see any JSON here, just JavaScript Objects.

Comment: If possible you can use an array of strings instead of an array of objects in b.secondObj, it becomes simpler to just do b.secondObj.includes("refFromA") for each item in a.firstObj.

Comment: @Ab.Progr I can not change from Object to array it's from API

Comment: Do you want to compare _id from b.secondObj with Ref from a.firstObj ?

Comment: yes If it' matched then assign a.firstObj element to b.secondObj.new=matching element [a.firstObj element]

Comment: Do you want to assign the last match or the first ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAI tested... yes it's matching. Take a look:

```js
var a={
  firstObj: 
    [
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      }
    ]  
};

var b={
  secondObj: [
    {
      _id: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53"
    },
    {
      _id: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c"
    },    
  ]
}


a.firstObj.map(item =>
               b.secondObj.map((_item, index) => {
               //console.log(_item._id.toString());
               //console.log(item.Ref.toString());
               if (_item._id == item.Ref) {
                   b.secondObj[index].new = item;
                    }
                })
);

console.log(b)
```

You probably missed something. If there's anything else you want to know, please reformulate and I'll change the answer.

Please understand that with this code, as a object has many equal Ref elements, the association will be with the last Ref.

Comment: I too verified and your snippet seems to be working fine. If there's anything else that's required, you can modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `map` with an inner `reduce`:

```js
var a={
  firstObj: 
    [
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hhhh"
      }
    ]  
};

var b={
  secondObj: [
    {
      _id: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53"
    },
    {
      _id: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c"
    },    
  ]
}


function mergeByEqProp (propA, propB, listA, listB) {
  return listB.map(function (b) {
    return listA.reduce(function (acc, a) {
      if (!acc && a[propA] === b[propB]) {
        return Object.assign({}, b, {new: a});
      }
      return acc;
    }, null);
  });
}


console.log(mergeByEqProp('Ref', '_id', a.firstObj, b.secondObj));
```

It first `map`s over the second list and then `reduce`s the items in the first list until it finds a match. As soon as it finds a match, it always returns that. I added that functionality because it looks like there is some repetition in `a.firstObj` (have a close look at the `Ref` properties). In case that's fine, just change the `if (!acc && a[propA] === b[propB]) {` part to `if (a[propA] === b[propB]) {`.

The `Object.assign` part deserves a bit of explanation as well:

First of all, in case you *don't* work in an ES6/ES2015+ environment, you need another function as a replacement – `$.extend` for example works well. Or write your own, like:

```
function assign (a /*, ...rest */) {
  var r = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return r.reduce(function (acc, x) {
    for (var y in x) {
      if (x.hasOwnProperty(y)) { acc[y] = x[y]; }
    }
    return acc;
  }, a);
}
```

The other thing to explain is the empty `{}`: It is merely there to create a *copy* first and alter that copy instead of the original item. If that doesn't bother you, just use `Object.assign(b, a)` (or your own `assign(b, a)` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

/* This code will identify all the items that match with Ref id and then assign them into new property inside the secondObj as an array */

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var a={
  firstObj: 
    [
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53",
        status: "abcd"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "efgh"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "hijk"
      },
      {
        Ref: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c",
        status: "lmno"
      }
    ]  
};

var b={
  secondObj: [
    {
      _id: "5ca3cd6aefbc9f1782b5db53"
    },
    {
      _id: "5ca3cdc6efbc9f1782b5db5c"
    },    
  ]
}

let equality = [];

for(let i=0; i<b.secondObj.length ; i++){
    let itemB = b.secondObj[i];
    equality.push(a.firstObj.filter(itemA => itemA.Ref == itemB._id)) ;
}
equality.map((value, index) => b.secondObj[index].new = value); //<=== in case if there are more than one equal items in firstObj

//equality.map((value, index) => b.secondObj[index].new = value[0]); <== only asign one item to 'new' 
 
console.log(b);

</script>
```